# Error resolving module specifier “firebase/app”

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, contact-form

I'm trying to use firebase to make contact form work.The project is working with webpack. Following all tutorials and documentation I put the code

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "LKJidsdkjoeiflkdsjfsidfjlsdisj",
    authDomain: "sdfklsdkj.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "sdfklsdkj",
    storageBucket: "sdfklsdkj.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1068439125174",
    appId: "1:1132132332:web:4ecfb3a687c92917617a17"
  };

 
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);nter code here
```

to special form.js file in the bottom of HTML:

```
    <script src="./src/assets/form.js"></script>
    <script src="./dist/main.js"></script>
```

And firefox console gives me this error: **import declarations may only appear at top level of a module**.
I tried to solve the issue and add type="module" in the script. And got another error in console:
**Error resolving module specifier “firebase/app”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”**. How to solve this issue?